# EspressoでcheckableなMenuItemのテスト

Tags: android

checkableなメニューアイテムのテストをしたいです。
通常のメニューアイテムは、以下のように表示状態を確認出来ますが、

```
onView(withText(R.string.action_one)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
            .perform(click());
```

このアイテムがcheckableなときに、そのチェック状態を確認したくて、以下のように書きましたが、階層内にViewが見つからないとエラーになりました。

```
onView(allOf(withClassName(endsWith("CheckBox")),hasSibling(withText(R.string.action_one))))
            .check(matches(isNotChecked()))
            .perform(click());
```

その時報告された階層ダンプ内には、CheckBoxが存在しています(AppCompatCheckBox)。
でも確かに"アクション１"を持つTextViewの兄弟ではないです。（1つ上にいるようです）

```
View Hierarchy:
+>PopupViewContainer{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=636, height=336, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+->DropDownListView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=588, height=288, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=true, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=24.0, y=24.0, child-count=2}
|
+-->ListMenuItemView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=588, height=144, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+--->RelativeLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=396, height=65, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=48.0, y=39.0, child-count=2}
|
+---->AppCompatTextView{id=2131492945, res-name=title, visibility=VISIBLE, width=396, height=65, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=アクション１, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+---->AppCompatTextView{id=2131492961, res-name=shortcut, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+--->AppCompatCheckBox{id=2131492960, res-name=checkbox, visibility=VISIBLE, width=96, height=96, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=444.0, y=24.0, text=, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false, is-checked=false}
|
+-->ListMenuItemView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=588, height=144, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=144.0, child-count=1}
|
+--->RelativeLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=492, height=65, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=48.0, y=39.0, child-count=2}
|
+---->AppCompatTextView{id=2131492945, res-name=title, visibility=VISIBLE, width=492, height=65, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=アクション２, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+---->AppCompatTextView{id=2131492961, res-name=shortcut, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
```

この場合、どう書けばいいか分かる方いらっしゃいましたら、ご教授下さい。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。

Qiitaに解決方法を投稿しましたので、もし良ければ参考にしてください。
http://qiita.com/kasa_le/items/b517146b532a17f40365

結局いろいろ試行錯誤して、質問にも載せたViewの階層状態を参考にして、次のようにMatcherを作りました。

Checkboxクラスのオブジェクトを全部受け取って、その親Viewが持つ子Viewの中からTextViewを探し、指定したタイトル文字列を持っているかチェックしています。

OSのバージョンが違ったらもしかしたらアウトかも知れませんが、support-libraryを使っている間は大丈夫な気がします・・・が、何も保証は出来ません。

```
public static MenuItemTitleMatcher withCheckBoxTitle(final String title) {
    return new MenuItemTitleMatcher(title);
}

public static class MenuItemTitleMatcher extends BaseMatcher<Object> {
    private final String title;

    public MenuItemTitleMatcher(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    TextView getChildTextView(ViewGroup view, String title) {
        int num = view.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            View child = view.getChildAt(i);
            if (child instanceof TextView) {
                if (title.equals(((TextView) child).getText())) {
                    return (TextView) child;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof CheckBox) {
            CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) o;
            ViewParent parent = checkbox.getParent();
            if (parent instanceof ListMenuItemView) {
                // 子のViewGroupからTextViewを探す
                int num = ((ListMenuItemView) parent).getChildCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                    View child = ((ListMenuItemView) parent).getChildAt(i);
                    if (child == o) continue;
                    if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
                        TextView textView = getChildTextView((ViewGroup) child, title);
                        if (textView != null)
                            return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description description) {
        description.appendText("expected with Title: ");
        description.appendText("" + title);
    }
}
```

使用方法

```
onView(allOf(withClassName(endsWith("CheckBox")),
            EspressoUtil.withCheckBoxTitle(getString(R.string.action_lock))))
            .check(matches(isNotChecked()))
            .perform(click());
```